# Why entity framework core rc2 lambda expressions select query load all properties that not exists in select

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, .net-core-rc2

Entity framework core rc2 generates bad sql query in sql profiler, Models and DbContext are given below, The reason for this issue is ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser, And this issue also true for other case that use inheritance.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set;}
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

When use query like this:

```
var list = _dbContext.Books.Select(e => new {
    e.Name,
    e.User.UserName
}).ToList();
```

Generated sql select all prpoerties of User entity, while only need UserName property from user in result as below:

```
SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[CourseId], [e].[CourseId1], [e].[Name], [e].[UserId],
[e.User].[Id], [e.User].[AccessFailedCount], [e.User].[ConcurrencyStamp],
[e.User].[Deleted], [e.User].[Email], [e.User].[EmailConfirmed], [e.User].[LockoutEnabled], 
[e.User].[LockoutEnd], [e.User].[NormalizedEmail], [e.User].[NormalizedUserName], 
[e.User].[PasswordHash], [e.User].[PhoneNumber], [e.User].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
[e.User].[SecurityStamp], [e.User].[TwoFactorEnabled], [e.User].[UserName]
FROM [Book] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [e.User] ON [e].[UserId] = [e.User].[Id]
ORDER BY [e].[UserId]
```

By Join query result is as I expect, query is like this:

```
var list2 = _dbContext.Books
    .Join(_dbContext.Users,
          entryPoint => entryPoint.UserId,
          entry => entry.Id,
          (entryPoint, entry) => new { entryPoint.Name, entry.UserName }).ToList();
```

But I prefer use first query due to greater readability.

Comment: Who said that Entity Framework would optimize your queries? With Azure charging by the second, Microsoft make more money if they slow your queries down.

Comment: plz read whole question

Comment: I did read the question. What's your point?

Comment: generated sql query select all properties of User, while in entity framework  select only UserName from User entity selected